# Set attribute to managed object

Tags: ios, core-data, ibaction

I'm fairly new to ios development and I'm trying to set some imagedata as an attribute of a mangedobject I've created.

I've read, and re-read the apple docs and can't seem to find what I'm looking for. I know it must be something simple I'm missing but I can't put my finger on it.

If anyone could point me in the right direction i would really appreciate it!

here's my current code:

```
    -IBAction saveSignature: (id) Sender {
       NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(mySignature.image);
       NSManagedObject *pilotSignature = [[NSEntityDescription
insertnewObjectForEntityForName:@"pilotsignature"
inManagedObjectContext: selfmanagedObjectContext]]
```

Comment: 1. issue: this won't even compile because of syntax errors

Comment: 2. issue: where is your managed object? you make some imageDaata but never use that.. which is also what the error means :)